# Postgres picks sequential scan instead of a much faster index scan on multiple INNER JOINs

Tags: postgresql, postgres-9.4

We have the following query:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Client c
INNER JOIN Address a1 ON c.Address1 = a1.Id
INNER JOIN Address a2 ON c.Address2 = a2.Id
INNER JOIN Address a3 ON c.Address3 = a3.Id
WHERE c.Status = 0
AND a1.Status = 0
AND a2.Status = 0
AND a3.Status = 0
AND c.Id = 'specific id'
```

As you can see, we join several times to the same table, using different foreign keys. All of the tables have a `Status` column, and we filter `Status = 0` for each table.

When analyzing this with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, one can see that the query planner chooses an index scan for all of the tables, **except** for one of the `Address` tables (the `a2` joined by `c.Address2`). This single table is scanned with a sequential scan for `Status = 0` and later joined with `c.Address2 = a2.Id`.

This strategy is much more costly than an index scan. We select just one `Client` row, so the whole query returns just one line, so the `c.Address2 = a2.Id` predicate is much more limiting than the `a2.Status = 0` one.

OK so I thought maybe there is something special with this foreign key, which causes the statistics to be misleading to the query optimizer. So I removed the join to `a2`, which left us with the following query:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Client c
INNER JOIN Address a1 ON c.Address1 = a1.Id
INNER JOIN Address a3 ON c.Address3 = a3.Id
WHERE c.Status = 0
AND a1.Status = 0
AND a3.Status = 0
AND c.Id = 'specific id'
```

But now the query optimizer uses a sequential scan on `a3`. `a1` is still scanned using the index.

I always thought the query optimizer uses the table statistics (`Address` in this case) together with the limiting query (`aX.Status = 0` and `c.AddressX = aX.Id`) to decide which plan to use. But here it's more than that. When I include the join to `a2`, it uses a sequential scan for `a2` and an index scan for the rest. When I remove the join to `a2`, it uses a sequential scan for `a3`. **So the chosen strategy for `a2` depends on whether the unrelated join to `a3` is present or not.**

What could be the reason for this behavior?

Please note that statistics is up to date and the tables have all been vacuuumed.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: `show join_collapse_limit`?..